# What is the mips logic of this relatioship $s1 = floor( log2 ($t0) )?

Tags: c, mips

This is C-fragment code given.

```
     addi $s1, $zero, 0

 loop: srl $t0, $t0, 1

     beq $t0, $zero, exit
     addi $s1, $s1, 1
     j loop 
exit
```

I am asked what is the relationship between $s1 and $t0. I can see from the C code that 
$t0 shifts right by 1 bit ($t0 = $t0/2) every loop until it becomes 0 and 
$s1 is simply $s1 = $s1 + 1, incrementing by 1 every loop
The answer given to the relationship is $s1 = floor( log2 ($t0) ), but i do not understand the logic behind this relationship.
Can someone explain this to me? 
Thanks

Comment: How many iterations of the loop do you think it takes until `$t0` becomes zero?

Answer (score 0):

The loop counts the number of successive right-shifts (i.e. divisions by 2) that can be performed on `$t0` without the result being zero.

That can also be expressed as finding the (zero-based) position of the leftmost `1`-bit in `$t0`. And since we only care about the leftmost `1` we can in turn express that as finding the largest integer **z** such that **2<sup>z</sup>** <= **$t0**.

We can take advantage of the relationship between logarithms and exponentiation, which is that

**log<sub>b</sub>(m) = n**  if  **b<sup>n</sup> = m**

So **$t0 = 2<sup>n</sup>** where **n = log<sub>2</sub>($t0)**, which also means that **$t0 = 2<sup>log<sub>2</sub>($t0)</sup>**

We are thus interested in finding the largest integer **z** such that **2<sup>z</sup> <= 2<sup>log<sub>2</sub>($t0)</sup>**

Since **2<sup>x</sup>** is a monotonically increasing function it follows that **2<sup>x</sup> <= 2<sup>y</sup>** for **x <= y**. So we can simplify what we're looking for to the largest integer **z** such that **z <= log<sub>2</sub>($t0)**, which is the definition of **floor(log<sub>2</sub>($t0))**.

Comment: @Micheal Oh I see! That makes it very clear. Thanks alot:)